# Finding the displacement given the final velocity and the change in time

Tags: kinematics

[Taken from this video.](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/one-dimensional-motion/acceleration-tutorial/v/airbus-a380-take-off-distance?modal=1)

I don't understand why he has to find the average velocity to find the displacement. If he knows the plane takes $78s$ to take off and that the velocity is $78m/s$ why not just do $78s * 78m/s = 6 084‬m$ or $\approx6km$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane is only going $78 \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ at the very end. If the plane was moving at that speed the entire time, you'd be correct in using the thought you have above, but the plane is *accelerating* at a constant rate. That means the velocity is changing. So, what we can do is take the average of the velocity, and then multiply that by the time.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at a geometrical arguement

[image]

The displacement of an object is given by the area of a curve (in calculus this is known as intgration). The area of a triangle is given by 
$$A=\frac{1}{2}ab$$
where $a$ and $b$ are both sides of a triangle. In this case $a=t$ and $b=v$, thus the displacement of an object is given by 
$$d=\frac{1}{2}vt$$

You can use other geometrical arguements like this to derive other kinematic equations.